# Automatically Exit SurfaceView

Tags: android

I have a game I'm developing for Android 2.x. When the player looses, I want to automatically exit that and go back to the previous menu of the game. This may be a simple question, but how do I do that?

I have a MenuActivity, which calls GameActivity, which calls the GameView (implementation of SurfaceView) where the game logic is.

UPDATE: No, wait, it's more complex than that. To make this game I followed the MoonLander example, which used threads.

**GameView**:

```
public class GameActivity extends Activity
{
GameView gameView;
GameThread gThread;

/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    gameView = new GameView(this);
    setContentView(gameView);

    gThread = gameView.getThread();
    gThread.doStart();
}
```

}

**GameView**:

```
package com.cp.balldrop;

public class GameView extends SurfaceView implements SurfaceHolder.Callback
{
    class GameThread extends Thread
    {


    public GameThread(SurfaceHolder sHolder, Context context, Handler handler)
    {
        //Code
    }

    public void doStart()
    {
        synchronized (mSurfaceHolder)
        {

        }
    }

    @Override
    public void run()
    {
        while (running)
        {
            Canvas c = null;
            try
            {
                c = mSurfaceHolder.lockCanvas(null);
                synchronized (mSurfaceHolder)
                {    
                    doDraw(c);
                }
            }
            finally
            {
                if (c != null)
                {
                    mSurfaceHolder.unlockCanvasAndPost(c);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    protected void doDraw(Canvas canvas)
    {
            //code
    }
}

/** Handle to the application context, used to e.g. fetch Drawables. */
private Context mContext;

/** Pointer to the text view to display "Paused.." etc. */
private TextView mStatusText;

/** The thread that actually draws the animation */
private GameThread gThread;

public GameView(Context context)
{
    super(context);

    // register our interest in hearing about changes to our surface
    SurfaceHolder holder = getHolder();
    holder.addCallback(this);

    // create thread only; it's started in surfaceCreated()
    gThread = new GameThread(holder, context, new Handler()
    {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message m)
        {
           // mStatusText.setVisibility(m.getData().getInt("viz"));
           // mStatusText.setText(m.getData().getString("text"));
        }
    });

    setFocusable(true);
}

public GameThread getThread()
{
    return gThread;
}

public void surfaceCreated(SurfaceHolder holder)
{
    gThread.start();
}

@Override
public void surfaceDestroyed(SurfaceHolder holder)
{
    boolean retry = true;
    gThread.setRunning(false);

    while (retry)
    {
        try
        {
            gThread.join();
            retry = false;
        }
        catch (InterruptedException e)
        {
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In my thread, I call the following method from my surfaceview's doTouch:

```
public void doLose() {
            synchronized (mSurfaceHolder) {
                //quit to mainmenu
                ((Activity) mContext).finish();
            }            
        }
```

This seems to shut down the surfaceview and the activity hosting it, dumping me back in my main-menu activity. Note the casting and the predefined context.

Answer (score 2):

What about calling [finish()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#finish%28%29) on the GameActivity?

Comment: Well, that exits GameActivity, but does so immediately after the game starts.

Comment: Then you should call it when the player looses.

Comment: @JesseJ @mibollma yeah, just call finish() wherever it is that you handle losing the game. The threading should handle itself since the surface will be destroyed and stop the thread at that point, although I would probably put a timeout in join.

Comment: Except finish() is for Activity, and handling loses is in SurfaceView. Each attempt to communicate between the two hasn't work.

Comment: Than how to communicate between those two is the main thing you have to figure out. There are lots of ways.