# How to finish an activity from surfaceView and call new activity with extras

Tags: android, android-activity

I am making a game application in android.  In this am having an menu activity which have  `setContentView(new MainGamePanel(this));`, MainGamePanel implements surface view where all my game functionaly is written. Now on some condition my game fail than i want to display a new Finish activity with score i accoured while playing. 
I this Finish activity i have two buttons one for replay and one for exit.

but am not getting how to finish activity from surfaceView and call a new activity with score.

Comment: Have you tried the startActivityForResult() / finishActivity() combo?

Comment: NO, i used an Intent, Intent.putextra for score and than start activity

Answer (score 0):

Look this link: 
[Automatically Exit SurfaceView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6638465/automatically-exit-surfaceview)

I used the next instruction:

```
((Activity) mContext).finish();
```

it works for me